# Robots Control Resolution

Tags: robotics

What I've known in my robotics course is that control resolution is given by this equation:
$Control Resolution = Total Range/2^n$
I'm actually confused whether $2^n$ is the number of bits or $n$ is the number of bits, and if the first case is the right one, what does $n$ stand for then, the same for the 2nd case, what does $2^n$ stand for? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what do your course notes say? Have you checked with your lecturer / TA?

Comment: I've checked some notes, it says that $2^n$ is the number of increments and $n$ is the number of bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2^n$ is the number of increments and $n$ is the number of bits